# SSHFS files from one server to another

Tags: server, filesystem, ssh, file-sharing, sshfs

I am trying to find the most secure way to transfer files from one server to another.

I have the following architecture:

[image: Architecture]

Currently I am using the main user `salamis` in order to mount the directories.

The files in the original directory are created through a PHP file manager `elfinder`.

Unfortunately, I am not able to `move`, `rename` or `delete` any file from the mounted directory through PHP. I get permission denied.

1) Is it because I mounted the filesystem using `salamis` instead of `www-data`?

2) Is it secure to mount the filesystem on `Server 2` as `www-data` ? If yes, how can I achieve that? `www-data` does not have a password and I cannot login using `su -m www-data`. I get `authentication failure`.

3) Can you think of a better architecture?

Answer (score 2):

SSHFS is a [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem. These are managed by a user-land process which runs as the user who mounts the filesystem: that `sshfs` process you run doubles as the filesystem driver. By default, most FUSE filesystems only allow the mounting user to access files inside.

In order to be able to access files through sshfs, you need three things:

1. The user who is authenticated over ssh on server1 must be able to access the files.
2. The user who tries to access the sshfs filesystem on server2 must have the necessary access permissions.
3. The user who tries to access the sshfs filesystem on server2 must be allowed to access that filesystem.

As I wrote above, only the mounting user has that last permission. You can relax this by adding `-o allow_user` to the `sshfs` command line, but this won't solve the other two problems. Note that `-o allow_user` only takes effect if `/etc/fuse.conf` contains `user_allow_user` or you are running `sshfs` as root.

On `server2`, you need to either run `sshfs` as the `www-data` user (whom you will have to give access to the SSH private key), or enable `allow_user` and arrange for the local `www-data` to have access to the files it needs. There are several ways to do that: through the `uid` option, or by passing `-o default_permissions`, or by passing `-o umask 770,gid=www-data`. If you enable `allow_user`, make sure that you don't end up allowing `www-data` to access more files than it should, and that you don't end up allowing other users to see or modify what they shouldn't. Running `sshfs` as `www-data` has the advantage of simplicity, you have a far better chance of not accidentally being too permissive.

For problem #1, you need to ssh into the `www-data` account on `server1`, or to allow the account that you use to access those files. There is some benefit in not allowing remote logins to system accounts such as `www-data`, because these make for poor auditing (you can't know who actually used the account). However, it's not out of the question, and it is somewhat easier to set up. If you don't want to allow remote logins to the `www-data` account, add `salamis`¹ to the `www-data` group, make sure that the filesystem on `server1` is mounted with the `acl` option (add it to the relevant entry in `/etc/fstab` if necessary), and add an [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) to `www-data`'s files:

```
setfacl -d -m group:www-data:rwx -R /path/to/www-root
setfacl -m group:www-data:rwx -R /path/to/www-root
```

¹  <sub>If that's your account on `server1`, I didn't understand from your question whether `salamis` was a user on `server1`, on `server2` or both.</sub>

Comment: `salamis` was a user on both servers. That's why I was using salamis to sshfs from one server to the other server

Comment: It's not enough for the user accounts to be the same name in unix. The userid (uid) and groupid (gid) need to match across sytems as well. Compare the entries for the 2 accounts in the /etc/passwd and /etc/group files on both systems and make sure they're in sync.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, just like Gilles answered, the login id you use are the default owner of created files. This is true for most protocolls.

2) Its correct there are no password for the www-data user. You can however give www-data a temporary password and copy salamis certificate to www-data with the command ssh-copy. When this is done salami can login and mount as www-data without input of any password. (You have to have a certificate built with ssh-keygen.)

3) Another possible solution are rsync the files between the two servers. Rsync uses the same secure infrastructure as ssh/sftp/sshfs, you can use ssh-copy just like you did in 2. With rsync you can let www-data fetch the files from salami. Using ssh-copy gives you the opportunity to script the syncing, a one-liner in /etc/cron.[dayly|hourly] is sufficient in most cases.  Rsync are robust, if there are any problems with the salamis-server your application can still be functional with the last files that you synced, your application are not slowed down by the network but you have a delay between a change in a file in salamis-directory and at the server. You can also consider using a VCS, for example bzr, and fetch your files from a repository. That gives you a nice revision control of your source codes.